# Manually testing a Ruby CLI

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

I'm building a CLI gem with Ruby using Thor. I run `rake install` which runs `rake build` then the task to install the gem locally. However when I try to run it in the commandline, it cannot locate the command. The gem is called `smokestack` so theoretically I *should* be able to run it in terminal once it's installed.

Structure:

```
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── bin
│   ├── console
│   ├── setup
│   └── smokestack
├── lib
│   ├── smokestack
│   │   ├── build.rb
│   │   ├── cli.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── smokestack.rb
├── pkg
│   └── smokestack-0.1.0.gem
├── smokestack.gemspec
└── test
    ├── build_test.rb
    ├── smokestack_test.rb
    └── test_helper.rb
```

---

bin/smokestack:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wU

require 'smokestack'

Smokestack::Cli.start(ARGV)
```

You can see in the tree the `pkg` folder from when I ran `rake install`. 
Here's the result when I run that:

```
smokestack 0.1.0 built to pkg/smokestack-0.1.0.gem.
smokestack (0.1.0) installed.
```

I then run `smokestack` in my terminal and get the error: `zsh: command not found: smokestack`

I've also tried `gem install --local ~/path/to/gem/pkg/gem.gem` 
Result:

```
Successfully installed smokestack-0.1.0
Parsing documentation for smokestack-0.1.0
Done installing documentation for smokestack after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

This results in the same 'command not found error'.

*Question* How am I supposed to run this CLI locally to test it out during development?

It ideally interacts with the current project it's in, so just running `bundle exec bin/smokestack` inside of it's own directory won't yield the results I need properly. It should be a system CLI anyway right?

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/juliusdelta/smokestack/tree/add-rspec-functionality) for additional context if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple things going wrong with this. First, bundle moved executable out of `/bin` to `/exe`. See [this article(http://bundler.io/blog/2015/03/20/moving-bins-to-exe.html) for reference.

I moved `bin/smokestack` to `exe/smokestack`.

You also have to make sure and stage your files, cause the `.gemspec` files gets the gem files list by running `git ls-files`. Now that all that is done, everything appears to be working.